# python, calculation on large 3d numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, performance, opencv, large-data

I have a numPy 3d array (for now, it is 200x200x200), and later I plan to use larger arrays (~500x500x500).

For each cell, I want to calculate the average values of its neighbors.
I implemented it using loops and NumPy, but it takes a lot of time to do it. I assume it is because I wrote it not efficiently:

```
def fun1(mat, R, C, D):
    for r in range(1, R - 2):
        for c in range(1, C - 2):
            for d in range(1, D - 2):
                new_val = (mat[r - 1, c, d] + mat[r + 1, c, d] + \
                            mat[r, c - 1, d] + mat[r, c + 1, d] + \
                            mat[r, c, d - 1] + mat[r, c, d + 1]) / 6
                mat[r, c, d] = new_val
    return mat

# R=C=D=200
# mat is a NumPy array with the size of RxCxD 

for iter in range(1000):
    mat = fun1(mat, R, C, D)
```

Is there any way to write it more efficiently?

The first step of my project was to solve this problem over 2D arrays. Then used the OpenCV function cv.filter2D, which was fast (compared to NumPy). But now, with the 3D matrix size, I am lost.

Thank you all for the help

Comment: skimage can deal with n-d arrays. -- yes, writing your own python loops is a terrible idea because you _should_ be using libraries to do the task. if you know of `numba` and use it, writing your own loops becomes acceptable again. -- please review [ask]. your research should have pointed you to libraries that can do convolution/correlation/filtering on 3D/N-D arrays.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html

Comment: This is very inefficient indeed. You need to use vectorized calls. Please start by reading the well-written official Numpy tutorial (or read the many past related questions about this on S.O.). The operation you try do implement manually is called a stencil and it is implemented in many different packages (AFAIK Scipy, Numpy, OpenCV, etc.). Moreover, this is a separable kernel so you can apply 2D stencils so to compute the 3D one. If you do that in a loop, then please use dedicated tools which do that much more efficiently. There are several decades of research on how to do that efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are probably one of the least efficient ways to write code in python - avoid them if you care about efficiency.
Numpy implements many vectorized operations that can speed up your code by orders of magnitude.

There are 6 direct neighbors per cell. We are going to exclude the outermost cells, as they do not have 6 neighbors.

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.random.rand(200,200,200) # create 3d array of random values

avg = np.random.rand(200,200,200) # array to paste the average values in

avg[1:-1,1:-1,1:-1] = (mat[0:-2,1:-1,1:-1] + mat[1:-1,0:-2,1:-1] + mat[1:-1,1:-1,0:-2,] + mat[2:,1:-1,1:-1] + mat[1:-1,2:,1:-1] + mat[1:-1,1:-1,2:]) / 6
```

This code will be much quicker than yours, because it vectorizes the operation (it does multiple operations at once!) instead of calculating the values one by one with the loop overhead.